# Stopping an UIView animation that was started but being delayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, delay

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:4 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn)
    animations:^
        {
            // do something here (irrelevant)
        }
        completion:nil
];
```

How do I stop the animation within the time of the delay? For example, I want to stop this animation after I execute it but before the delay timer ends. I've tried `[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];` but to no avail.

EDIT: As I've stated. **I've tried `[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];` but to no avail.**

Comment: Have you tried wrap it like this: `[CATransaction begin];[theView.layer removeAllAnimations];[CATransaction commit]`;

Comment: Can u please show the code inside the `animationWithDuration`. Maybe your `removeAllAnimations` is on another view and not on the view u want to cancel?! :/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but you can stop all animations with `[view.layer removeAllAnimations];` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSTimer` and then just call `[timer invalidate]` if you no longer want the animation to run.

E.g.:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4 target:self selector:@selector(animateView:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

// Then stop...

[timer invalidate];
```